# Magento : Multiple Taxes for different Simple Products associated with a Single Configurable Product

Tags: magento-1.9, configurable-product, tax, tax-class, associate-products

I have two simple products associated with a configurable product. However, each of the simple product has a different tax rate applicable to it. It appears Magento picks the tax class of the configurable product and applies it to all simple products. Can I have Magento pick the Tax Class / Tax Rate of the simple product instead?